# How to Identify values from characteristic data for Walk Run Stride bluetooth sensor

Tags: swift, performance, core-bluetooth, characteristics, cadence

I am developing a workout app with sensor connectivity and able to read and get data for Heart rate sensor but for stride sensors (walk/Run) facing problem to map the values given by sensor characteristic.

How will I get Speed, cadence, steps per mints , Distance.?
I searched on google didn't get for this.

I am pretty much sure getting data but difficulty in mapping index and values for different parameters.

Check attached code snapshot for data output.

Thanks in Advance...!!

[image]

Comment: Your image is only showing the first 5 of 16 characters.  Three of the characters are binary zero.  It might be helpful to list the 16 characters as data in your question.

Comment: I need this kind of description for bytes index values :  https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor#toc-anchor-011

Answer (score 0):

This question should not be tagged `cadence`, unless I'm missing something? That tag if for "A global provider of Electronic Design Automation (EDA) software and engineering services."

---

PS: I can't comment yet, please resolve this and delete this answer.